# How to use and operator in python?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, operator-keyword

I want to make a function that will remove '-' from two sequences of char if both contain it. This is my code.

```
def normalized(seq1, seq2):
    x = ''
    y = ''
    for a, b in zip(seq1, seq2):
    if a != '-' and b != '-':
        print a,b, 'add'
        x += a
        y += b
    else:
        print a, b, 'remove'
return x,y

x = 'ab--dfd--df'
y = 'rt-bfdsu-vf'

print normalized(x, y)
```

and this is the result.

```
a r add
b t add
- - remove
- b remove
d f add
f d add
d s add
**- u remove**
- - remove
d v add
f f add
('abdfddf', 'rtfdsvf')
```

You can see that `-` and `u` should not be removed. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: But `- b` should be removed?

Comment: And your indentation is broken, can you fix it please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to remove if *both* are `-`, then test for that:

```
if not (a == '-' and b == '-'):
```

which can be shortened to:

```
if not (a == b == '-'):
```

or use `or` instead of `and` to remove the `not`:

```
if a != '-' or b != '-':
```

but that is not as readable.

Perhaps no more readable, but the list comprehension would be:

```
def normalized(seq1, seq2):
    return [''.join(v) for v in zip(*[(a, b) 
                for a, b in zip(seq1, seq2) if not (a == b == '-')])]
```

or using `map()`, sufficient for Python 2:

```
def normalized(seq1, seq2):
    return map(''.join, zip(*[(a, b) for a, b in zip(seq1, seq2) if not (a == b == '-')]))
```

Comment: de Morgan's law simplifies this in @mgilson answer.

Comment: or `if not a == b == '-':`

Comment: this one `if not (a == b == '-'):` works. I just miss the logic here :p Thanks for your reduced code :D

Comment: @user2435611: The part in the parenthesis is only `True` if both `a` and `b` are equal and both are equal to `-`. The `not` just turns that around to when `a` is not equal to `b`, or if they are, at least not equal to `-`.

Comment: Yes, your code is just what I want to do and you reduce it into 2 lines only :D Thanks a lot

Comment: Just wondering what '*' means here `map(''.join, zip(*[(a, b) for a, b in zip(seq1, seq2) if not (a == b == '-')]))`?

Comment: @user2435611: We apply the output of the `[...]` list comprehension as separate parameters to `zip()`, effectively transposing rows to columns. See [Fast matrix transposition in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2921681)

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `or`, not `and` ...

---

Another clever way that you could do this is to use [operator chaining](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

```
if a == b == '-':
   print a,b, 'remove'
else:
   print a,b, 'add'
   x += a
   y += b
```

This is extremely succint and clear that you want to remove the dashes only if they appear in **both** strings.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan it is equivalent to `(a ==b and b == '-')`

Comment: It's called operator chaining as mgilson wrote and is a feature of python ;-) you can also do `5 < x < 10` instead of `x > 5 and x < 10` etc.

Comment: It's documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, Septi, mgilsom ..nice feature.. it don't happen in our C :)

Answer (score 1):

The condition should be `not (a =='-' and b == '-')`:

```
def normalized(seq1, seq2):
    x = ''
    y = ''
    for a, b in zip(seq1, seq2):
        if not (a =='-' and b == '-'):  # you need `not` here
            print a,b, 'add'
            x += a
            y += b
        else:
            print a, b, 'remove'
    return x,y

x = 'ab--dfd--df'
y = 'rt-bfdsu-vf'

print normalized(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, `- u` shoud be removed.

In fact,

```
a != '-' and b != '-' is False
```

the first part is false and the second is true. False and True is False. (Boolean Algebra 101, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations for details)

Answer (score 0):

You are currently asking for the program to match when a and b are not "-". This means that unless both are not equal to "-" then it will go to your else. The code you want is:

```
def normalized(seq1, seq2):
    x = ''
    y = ''
    for a, b in zip(seq1, seq2):
        if a == '-' and b == '-':
            print a,b, 'remove'
        else:
            print a, b, 'add'
            x += a
            y += b
    return x,y

x = 'ab--dfd--df'
y = 'rt-bfdsu-vf'

print normalized(x, y)
```

Comment: Why are you adding while printing `'remove'`? :-)

Comment: Oops, that was a horribly hacked together bit of code but yeah the addition goes on the else. I'll edit that now.