# How to convert lists in a dictionary to dictionaries in a lists (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have multiple lists in a dictionary:

```
stock = {
  'code': ['1942', '1942', '1942', '1942'], 
  'high': [782, 771, 764, 765],
  'date': ['2015-07-15', '2015-07-14', '2015-07-13',  '2015-07-10',],
  'close': [780, 768, 763, 753],
  'open': [767, 770, 756, 762]
}
```

I want to convert these lists to dictionaries in a list:

```
converted = [
  {'code': '1942', 'high': 782, 'date': '2015-07-15', 'close': 780, 'open': 767},
  {'code': '1942', 'high': 771, 'date': '2015-07-14', 'close': 768, 'open': 770},
  {'code': '1942', 'high': 764, 'date': '2015-07-13', 'close': 763, 'open': 756},
  {'code': '1942', 'high': 765, 'date': '2015-07-12', 'close': 753, 'open': 762},
]
```

The final goal is to output a csv file by using the dictionaries but I got stuck here. I am not completely sure about how to get the result. It'd be great if you could give me some advice. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not ask us to write code for you as SO is not a code writing service. Do add your attempts. We will be more than happy to help you out if you are struck in your attempts. All the best

Comment: Where did the last line in your expected output come from? Your input has no `2015-07-12` date, only `2015-07-10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [transpose the dictionary values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921681/fast-matrix-transposition-in-python) with the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), the pair these up with the keys (using `zip()` again) to make new dictionaries:

```
cols = zip(*stock.values())
converted = [dict(zip(stock, column)) for column in cols]
```

or, combined into one line:

```
converted = [dict(zip(stock, column)) for column in zip(*stock.values())]
```

Demo:

```
>>> stock = {
...   'code': ['1942', '1942', '1942', '1942'], 
...   'high': [782, 771, 764, 765],
...   'date': ['2015-07-15', '2015-07-14', '2015-07-13',  '2015-07-10',],
...   'close': [780, 768, 763, 753],
...   'open': [767, 770, 756, 762]
... }
>>> [dict(zip(stock, column)) for column in zip(*stock.values())]
[{'close': 780, 'date': '2015-07-15', 'high': 782, 'code': '1942', 'open': 767}, {'close': 768, 'date': '2015-07-14', 'high': 771, 'code': '1942', 'open': 770}, {'close': 763, 'date': '2015-07-13', 'high': 764, 'code': '1942', 'open': 756}, {'close': 753, 'date': '2015-07-10', 'high': 765, 'code': '1942', 'open': 762}]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_, compact=True)
[{'close': 780, 'code': '1942', 'date': '2015-07-15', 'high': 782, 'open': 767},
 {'close': 768, 'code': '1942', 'date': '2015-07-14', 'high': 771, 'open': 770},
 {'close': 763, 'code': '1942', 'date': '2015-07-13', 'high': 764, 'open': 756},
 {'close': 753, 'code': '1942', 'date': '2015-07-10', 'high': 765, 'open': 762}]
```

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot. Simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use zip and map:

```
converted = map(lambda b: dict(zip(stock.keys(),b)), zip(*stock.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip`:

```
converted = [dict(x) for x in zip(*[[(k, tv) for tv in v] for k, v in stock.iteritems()])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like that might help?

```
stock ={
    'code': ['1942', '1942', '1942', '1942'],
    'high': [782, 771, 764, 765],
    'date': ['2015-07-15', '2015-07-14', '2015-07-13',  '2015-07-10'],
    'close': [780, 768, 763, 753],
    'open': [767, 770, 756, 762]
}
new_list = []
min_length = min([len(stock[prop]) for prop in stock])

for x in range(min_length):
    new_prop = {}
    for prop in stock:
        new_prop[prop] = stock[prop][x]
    new_list.append(new_prop)

print new_list
```